# Insertar datos en dos tablas

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Tengo dos tablas en mysql, `tabla1` y `tabla2`.

Lo que intento es insertar datos en el campo `nombre` de la `tabla1` y que a la vez, al realizar este insert, se inserten los mismos datos en el campo `nombre` de la `tabla2`.

He creado ambas columnas como claves primarias y he creado una relación entre ambas desde `phpmyadmin`, pero no funciona.

¿Como seria la forma correcta de realizarse?

Comment: Busca documentación sobre los `trigger` Te permitirán hacer justamente lo que pides.

Comment: Te apoyas de algún lenguaje de programación? Ej: `PHP`

Comment: Para realizar el `insert` no, lo realizo directamente desde el `phpmyadmin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer un trigger para que te inserte el nombre de la tabla1 en la tabla2.

seria algo como:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER insertarNombre
AFTER INSERT
ON tabla1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tabla2(ID, Nombre)
    VALUES(new.ID, new.Nombre);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Aunque también depende si estas trabajando con otro lenguaje en conjunto. Por ejemplo si es una pagina web, con PHP y AJAX puedes conseguir esto sin necesidad de hacer un trigger.